# Converting UTF-16 QByteArray to QString

Tags: qt, unicode

I have a QByteArray which contains bytes in UTF-16 format.

A Java program sends data to a QT program via socket using

```
//dos is DataOutPutStream
dos.writeChars("hello world");
```

On the receiver side in QT program I read the data from socket into QByteArray and I want to convert it to a QString. inspecting the data variable of QByteArray it has 0h0e0l0l0o0 0w0o0r0l0d

When I try to make a QString out of it like this

```
QString str(byteArray)
```

The resulting string is empty perhaps because it encounters a 0 byte at the start and ofcouse because the documentation of the constructor I am using says that it internally uses fromAscii and what I am passing is not ascii.

I guess i have to somehow use QString::fromUTF-16 but that requires a ushort* and I have a QbyteArray.

Please advise what is the best way to do it.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get a pointer to the [QByteArray.data()](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7-snapshot/qbytearray.html#data-2)  and cast it to ushort*

Comment: ok the function worked but did not get the right QString . it contains wired hexadecimals numbers

Comment: I am not sure the data in QbyteArray is something like 0h0e0l0l0o0 0w0o0r0l0d  - notice there is no null charcter at end... so I manually specified size in the QString::fromUTF-8 as second param but same thing.  My platform in Windows 7

Comment: guess you seem right I created a temp QString object and converted it to QByteArray like this QByteArray b((const char*) (s.utf16()), s.size() * 2); the contents are like t 0 e 0 s 0 t 0 So how would I fix that

Comment: Use `ntohs(uint16_t net)` - you might need to include the networking headers, I don't remember if there is a qt fucntion for it

Comment: I am confused why would a network change byte order of data ? I thought byte order in networks has to do with ports and address only ? so ntohs stuff would probably be need for ports and addresses and not data :(

Comment: Bytes in a short on an intel CPU are stored in the 'wrong' order (little endian = lo byte - hi byte). Because you don't know what brand of CPU is on the other end of a network connection you generally send bytes over a network in network order (big endian, hi-lo) you then convert them to host order (if necessary). I was suggesting that whatever protocol your Java socket is using - it's assuming network order

Comment: Worked it out finally, dos.writeChars("hello world"); was explicitly writting as big endian even though the native endianess on that platform is low-endian. I am now sending bytes from java after converting them to utf-16 which is in low-endian and it translates fine in QT . Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

This would work, assuming your utf-16 data is of the same endianness or has the BOM (Byte Order Mark):

```
QByteArray utf16 = ....;
auto str = QString::fromUtf16(
                reinterpret_cast<const ushort*>(utf16.constData()));
```

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14131127/qbytearray-to-qstring/14131215

Comment: @FIKo Using the heavy (ICU-based, typically) text codec when `QString` can do it by itself... why?

Comment: Just an addition in case when there's a different endianess or the endianess is not known. For standard situations your example should work flawlessly.

Comment: Unknown endianness different than that of the system's is not handled anywhere, because any assumption has a 50% chance of being wrong. Known endianness, declared by BOMs, is handled just fine by `fromUtf16`. There's a reason `QString` supports utf16 natively: it'd be rather silly to have to pull the extremely heavy (many megabytes!) ICU or similar machinery just to do what `QString` has written on the box.

Comment: @ Kuba Ober You're certainly right, so I have nothing to add here.