# QByteArray to QString

Tags: c++, qt, qstring, qtcore, qbytearray

I'm having issues with `QByteArray` and `QString`.

I'm reading a file and stores its information in a `QByteArray`. The file is in unicode, so it contains something like: `t\0 e\0 s\0 t\0 \0 \0`

I'm trying to compare this value to my specified value, but it fails, because in the debugger I see it's not an unicode string.

The code will explain everything:

```
QByteArray Data; //contains unicode string "t\0 e\0 s\0 t\0 \0 \0"
QString myValue = "test"; //value to compare.
if(Data.contains(myValue))
    //do some stuff.
else
    //do other stuff.
```

In the debugger, it shows me that the variable `Data` has the value `"t\0 e\0 s\0 t\0 \0 \0"` and `myValue` has the value `"test"`. How can I fix it?

Comment: Possibly useful: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#converting-between-8-bit-strings-and-unicode-strings

Comment: Please note that string handling changed since Qt 5.0. Character arrays are internally interpreted as being UTF-8 encoded. `QString myValue = "äöü"`; for example should be avoided at least if the source file it self is not stored in UTF-8. Take a look at https://wiki.qt.io/Strings_and_encodings_in_Qt for more information.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use [QTextCodec](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextcodec.html#codecForMib) to convert the bytearray to a string:

```
QString DataAsString = QTextCodec::codecForMib(1015)->toUnicode(Data);
```

(1015 is UTF-16, 1014 UTF-16LE, 1013 UTF-16BE, 106 UTF-8)

From your example we can see that the string `"test"` is encoded as  `"t\0 e\0 s\0 t\0 \0 \0"` in your encoding, i.e. every ascii character is followed by a `\0`-byte, or resp. every ascii character is encoded as 2 bytes. The only  unicode encoding in which ascii letters are encoded in this way, are UTF-16 or UCS-2 (which is a restricted version of UTF-16), so in your case the 1015 mib is needed (assuming your local endianess is the same as the input endianess).

Comment: Not sure why this is a so upvoted reply. This is giving an unusual solution that the majority uses and should use. Providing it alongside the usual conversion methods would have been a good reply, but on its own, it is strange.

Comment: @LaszloPapp: Do you mean `QString::fromUTf16`? That takes a ushort pointer, which would require some very ugly casting to pass a `QByteArray`

Comment: @BeniBela: yes, but why cannot it be utf8? In which case why not suggest from/toUtf8()?

Comment: @LaszloPapp: Because of the example. He wants to convert `t\0e\0s\0t\0` to `test`. If it were utf-8, there would be no `\0`-bytes

Comment: @BeniBela: OK, fair enough. Can you make this clear in your answer why you suggest utf16? As you can see, it was a bit unclear for me. You will also get a few more upvotes with the bumping of the thread. :)

Answer (score 50):

You can use this QString constructor for conversion from QByteArray to QString:

QString(const QByteArray &ba)

```
QByteArray data;
QString DataAsString = QString(data);
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  Functional and simpler (let Qt handle conversion automatically)

Answer (score 28):

You can use:

```
QString::fromStdString(byteArray.toStdString())
```

Answer (score 14):

you can use `QString::fromAscii()`

```
QByteArray data = entity->getData();
QString s_data = QString::fromAscii(data.data());
```

with `data()` returning a `char*`

for QT5, you should use `fromCString()` instead, as `fromAscii()` is deprecated, see <strike>https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-21872</strike> https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-21872

Comment: *Ascii() is deprecated in Qt 5! Do _not_ use it.

Comment: Actually he can not use any of this, because he wants to convert utf-16, not ascii

Comment: I can't seem to find `fromCString()`, did you mean (or was the method renamed since the Q / A) to [`fromCFString()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#fromCFString) ?

Comment: No actually use fromLatin1 instead of fromAscii

Answer (score 10):

You may find [QString::fromUtf8()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#fromUtf8) also useful.

For `QByteArray input` of `"\010"` and `"\000"`,

[QString::fromLocal8Bit(input, 1)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#fromLocal8Bit) returns `"\010"` and `""`

[QString::fromUtf8(input, 1)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#fromUtf8) correctly returns `"\010"` and `"\000"`.

Comment: Although he needs fromUtf16, I like this answer too.  Tidy yet specific.

Answer (score 6):

Use `QString::fromUtf16((ushort *)Data.data())`, as shown in the following code example:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    // QByteArray to QString
    // =====================

    const char c_test[10] = {'t', '\0', 'e', '\0', 's', '\0', 't', '\0', '\0', '\0'};
    QByteArray qba_test(QByteArray::fromRawData(c_test, 10));
    qDebug().nospace().noquote() << "qba_test[" << qba_test << "]"; // Should see: qba_test[t

    QString qstr_test = QString::fromUtf16((ushort *)qba_test.data());
    qDebug().nospace().noquote() << "qstr_test[" << qstr_test << "]"; // Should see: qstr_test[test]

    return a.exec();
}
```

This is an alternative solution to the one using QTextCodec. The code has been tested using Qt 5.4.

Answer (score 1):

Qt 5.12 and up:

```
QString::fromStdString(byteArray.toStdString());
```