# QT c++ QSplitter saveState and restoreState

Tags: c++, qt

I have a splitter and I want to save his state in file with JSON.

```
QJsonObject mainJson;
// here I have to convert QByteArray to QString
mainJson.insert("test", QTextCodec::codecForMib(1015)->toUnicode(ui->splitter->saveState()));

QFile file("test.json");
QTextStream textStream;
file.open(QFile::WriteOnly);
textStream.setDevice(&file);
textStream.setCodec("UTF-8");
textStream << QString(QJsonDocument(mainJson).toJson()).toUtf8();
textStream.flush();
file.close();
```

But file contains this:

> \u0000＀\u0000Ā\u0000Ȁ\u0000Ⰱ\u0000쐀\u0000\u0000Ā\u0000Ȁ

Is that ok? And how to convert this back to `QByteArray` for `ui->splitter->restoreState(...);`?
PS: I use code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14131127/qbytearray-to-qstring)

Comment: Why do you want to save the status of the QSplitter as JSON?

Comment: @eyllanesc I have a lot of options in program as json and I want to save splitter state as json too. I want to save state of splitter after reloading

Comment: I suggest to use QSettings

Comment: @Fabio I can`t. I need to save in the file

Comment: QSettings can save in file, but it use the INI format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic in general is to convert the QByteArray to QString, in this case I prefer to convert it to base64 than to use a codec for unicode to avoid the problems of compression and decompression.

Considering the above, the solution is:

**Save:**

```cpp
QJsonObject mainJson;
QByteArray state = spliter->saveState();
mainJson.insert("splitter", QJsonValue(QString::fromUtf8(state.toBase64())));
QFile file("settings.json");
if(file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)){
    file.write(QJsonDocument(mainJson).toJson());
    file.close();
}
```

**Restore:**

```cpp
QJsonDocument doc;
QFile file("settings.json");
if(file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)){
    doc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(file.readAll());
    file.close();
}
if(doc.isObject()){
    QJsonObject obj = doc.object();
    QByteArray state = QByteArray::fromBase64(obj.value("splitter").toString().toUtf8());
    spliter->restoreState(state);
}
```